# conditionally call a function with its params

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having several functions, I would like do not call them if there is no need (logic in `needToCalculate`), used by a generic function `calculateIfNeeded`

```
// helper functions
function sum(a: number, b: number) { return a + b; }  // complex real logic (CRL)
function bum(a: number, code: string) { return (code=="B") ? a*a : a+a; } // CRL
function zum(code: string) { return (code=="Z") ? 5 : 8; }                // CRL

function needToCalculate(code: string) {return false} // CRL
```

Question: what type should have the param `func` of the method `calculateIfNeeded` bellow?

```
// calculator function
function calculateIfNeeded(code: string, func: ???, ...args: any[]){
    return needToCalculate(code) ? func(args): NaN
}

// main function
let a = 4, b = 9

let res = calculateIfNeeded("A", sum, a, b);  console.log(res);    
res = calculateIfNeeded("B", bum, a, "B");    console.log(res);    
res = calculateIfNeeded("C", zum, "Z");       console.log(res);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwBQEMBcizoBGApgE4A0iheBaJpAlIgN6KnFQilJaIDUVANwBfRAHoxiCHDQAHADbEAHm2JZ5ieXADmMCAChQkWAirpsNImUrSAJsTzIopGGG0NLdMi1WduiDDtiAF5ggCIAITCmAH5ELAAqXjwsPixBRFEJKRkFZVV1TR09Q3BoeCQAL3Mgx2dXd096H3Y-JEC4e1CwgC1oxDiAVkQ8AA4MrMlpOUUVdkKtXQNS4wr8YmJbABU4AGF1CBB5LChiDvs6lzcGZlauJGB1ZGJhbOm8ubUNRZKV8tMIAcjidiABJYAAOQ29ls5wcKHqbkoRggeBi6MoADpsVhSNpkCkwABPADaAF0bvpENTfPd1psdvt5Idjqc4bFECjsHjkB58Ed5PphPp9IooPFEMFEAAWSiESWIACcIrFqmQCsBzOBp3BUM2mwwYQAgmFKKg0JQsHKGPppGBkHBFJjFhh2LyRW6NUDWWDIdCDZFTWYLfFKIGbXaHU6XW6bfpPVLNSyQbr-bCwrsg9UQ71oraEFHiM6dK7iLygA)

Comment: `function calculateIfNeeded<F extends ResultFunction>(code: string, func: F, ...args: Parameters<F>)`

Comment: This could help you out: https://www.becomebetterprogrammer.com/typescript-pass-function-as-a-parameter/

Comment: also, pay attention that your code won't work and you need to call `func(...args)`

Comment: @OmriAttiya why did you delete your answer it seemed OK to me

Comment: there is a better solution like @DimaParzhitsky suggested, I'll improve my answer now

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky what? could you elaborate, with a sample?

Comment: @serge Omri Attiya will help you. Thanks, Omri!

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky, not sure on the example of Omri if it's correct, especially the Parameters<F> part not exposed

Comment: @serge Omri went a slightly different way: infer function type from a given type of parameter list. My suggestion was the reverse – to infer type of parameter list from function type. Either is fine, there's no preferred way (as long as it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending upon my comment, you will have to add a parameter type, constraint it to the type of the function you want to use as `func`, and infer the type of `args` from that:

```
/**
 * This represents not just _any function_, but one that can be
 * given as the second parameter (`func`) of `calculateIfNeeded`.
 * The call signature must be added explicitly, because apparently
 * TypeScript cannot know, that a union of callables is also callable
 */
type Func = (typeof sum | typeof bum | typeof zum) & ((...args: never[]) => number);

function calculateIfNeeded<F extends Func>(code: string, func: F, ...args: Parameters<F>): number {
    return needToCalculate(code) ? func(...args): NaN;
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/Na17EN)*.

Note, that I had to change `func(args)` to `func(...args)`, because `args` is an array, but neither of `sum`, `bum`, or `zum` accepts an array as an argument.

Comment: The note is important, now I see your answer, but it took me almost an hour to understand the problem before today ) Pasib.

Answer (score 2):

since it looks like you can return anything from the calculation (assuming you're not limited by any restrictions), the type of `func` will be

```
func: (...args: any[]) => any
```

That means you expected to receive in `func` any number of arguments with any type, and expect to return from `func` any type.

EDIT (inspired by *@Dima Parzhitsky* comment):

You can so something like this:

```
function calculateIfNeeded<F extends any[]>(code: string, func: (...args: F)=>number, ...args: F) : number{
    return needToCalculate(code) ? func(...args): NaN
}
```

Define `F` to be some extension of any arguments (`any[]`).

Then the `func` receives `F` and return `any`, and the args themselves are `F` as well.

Then you just call `func(...args)`

Comment: "extends any[]" ? that is the result type isn't it?

Comment: suppose the function takes `...any[]` and always returns `number`

Comment: using `<whatever>` means we use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). The return type comes after the function: `function name() : *ReturnType*`

Comment: @serge in that case, just change the return type to number (i edit it in post)

Comment: probably the signature would be `<F extends (...args: any[]) => number>`

Comment: @serge no.. that is a different thing (which you can also do) but its was not my intention. If you do it, you only define the type for `func`. what I wanted to do was to make sure `func` receive the same args that pass to `args`

Comment: `args: Parameters<F>` would assure that (see original Dima comment)